# Використання скорочень "стор." "с." "ст." "стр." "сс." тощо для позначення сторінок у бібліографічному описі книги

Tags: правопис, скорочення

Моє питання може здатися непотрібним, та все ж задам його. Цікавить чи є десь праці наукові-бібліографічні, де пояснено, яке скорочення потрібно використовувати ("стор.", "с.", "стр." чи "сс.") для позначення сторінок у бібліографічному описі книги у *сучасній українській мові*.

Моє поточне розуміння:

- "стор." — найбільш прийнятний варіант для позначення загальної кількості сторінок у бібліографії книги (аналог англійського "p.");
- "с.", "стр." — пережитки минулого. Такі самі скорочення використовують в російській мові, і тому використання цих скорочень у сучасному українському мовознавстві є небажаним;
- "сс." — позначення діапазону сторінок, як наприклад "92–98 сс." — це всі сторінки з 92 по 98 включно. Не впевнений, що таке зараз існує (аналог англійського "pp.").

Зауваги:

1) [Вже є схоже запитання](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14533/usage-of-p-versus-pp-versus-pg-to-denote-page-numbers-and-page-ranges) в анг. SE.

2) Відповідь у стилі посилання на *[стандарт ДСТУ ГОСТ 7.1:2006 «Бібліографічний запис. Бібліографічний опис. Загальні вимоги та правила складання»](https://web.archive.org/web/20161213030924/http://www.ukrbook.net:80/zakony/metodrek.pdf)* — це не зовсім те що я шукаю. Хоча посилатися на цю працю ніхто не забороняє (як і на MLA, Chicago style тощо), бо я вважаю, що кращий метод створення бібліографії книжок українською — це використання стилю штибу MLA (і просто використовувати MLA українською, а не англійською), бо ДСТУ ГОСТ 7.1:2006 — це якась дика темінь і совковий архаїзм для мене (який провів усе своє післяшкільне освітнє життя в західних університетах, де MLA/Chicago style — це всьо).

Comment: «Такі самі скорочення використовують в російській мові, і тому використання цих скорочень у сучасному українському мовознавстві є небажаним» — я б не сказав, що використання чогось у російській мові має бути аргументом проти використання цього в нас. Щодо «стр.» я майже згоден: це в російській «стр[аница]», а в нас «стор[інка]» (якщо брати до літери «р»); але от чим «с[торінка]» не догодило — не розумію. (А мені особисто найбільше «ст[орінка]» подобається ще зі школи — не надто довге і не надкоротке.)

Comment: @Sasha, [ДСТУ 3582:2013 Інформація та документація. Бібліографічний опис. Скорочення слів і словосполучень в українській мові.. Загальні вимоги та правила. (ISO 4:1984, NEQ; ISO 832:1994, NEQ). На заміну ДСТУ 3582-97.](http://zakon.gbb.com.ua/regulations/10637/487553/) визначено, що **`сторінка`** скорочується як **`с.`**

Comment: А ще іноді бачив «арк[уш]» — хоча не знаю, наскільки це доречно, бо _аркуш_ теоретично — дві сторінки (лист) або навіть [шістнадцять сторінок](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1578&page=72).

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, я мав на увазі, що не розумію фраз «пережитки минулого» і «використовують в російській мові… тому використання… є небажаним» у даному контексті.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ваші побажання вже враховано.

[Наказом Міністерства освіти і науки України 12.01.2017 № 40](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0155-17) затверджено Вимоги до оформлення дисертації.

Зазначені вимоги визначають структуру та правила оформлення дисертації, зокрема й списку використаних джерел.

> 11. Список використаних джерел формується здобувачем наукового ступеня за його вибором (опціонально - в кінці кожного розділу основної
>       частини дисертації) одним із таких способів:
>
> у порядку появи посилань у тексті;
>
> в алфавітному порядку прізвищ перших авторів або заголовків;
>
> у хронологічному порядку.
>
> Бібліографічний опис списку використаних джерел у дисертації може
>   оформлятися здобувачем наукового ступеня **за його вибором** з
>   урахуванням **Національного стандарту України ДСТУ 8302:2015
>   «Інформація та документація. Бібліографічне посилання. Загальні 
>   положення та правила складання»** або **одним зі стилів, віднесених до
>   рекомендованого переліку стилів оформлення списку наукових публікацій,
>   наведеного у додатку 3 до цих Вимог.**
>
> Бібліографічний опис використаного джерела може обмежуватися
>   обов’язковою інформацією, необхідною для однозначної ідентифікації
>   цього джерела.

Додаток 3 до Вимог містить **Рекомендований перелік стилів оформлення списку наукових публікацій**

> 1. MLA (Modern Language Association) style.
> 2. APA-1,2 (American Psychological Association) style.
> 3. Chicago/Turabianstyle-1.
> 4. Harvard style-1.
> 5. ACS (American Chemical Society) style.
> 6. AIP (American Institute of Physics) style.
> 7. IEEE (Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers) style.
> 8. Vancouver style-1.
> 9. OSCOLA.
> 10. APS (American Physics Society) style-1.
> 11. Springer MathPhys Style-1.

Якщо ж дотримуватись безпосередньо вимог вищезгаданого [ДСТУ 8302:2015](http://library.nlu.edu.ua/Biblioteka/sait/DSTU_8302-2015.pdf) (який вже навряд чи можна вважати таким архаїстичним), то в Загальних положеннях зазначається:

> 4.4 Елементи бібліографічного запису (заголовок і бібліографічний опис) та знаки пунктуації в бібліографічному посиланні, незалежно від
>   його призначення та виду, подають згідно з ДСТУ ГОСТ 7.80 і ДСТУ ГОСТ
>   7.1 з урахуванням таких особливостей:
>
> — у заголовку бібліографічного запису подають відомості про одного,
>   двох чи трьох авторів, при цьому імена цих авторів у бібліографічному
>   описі у відомостях про відповідальність (за навскісною рискою) не
>   повторюють;
>
> — за потреби у заголовку бібліографічного запису позатекстового
>   посилання можна зазначати більше ніж три імені авторів;
>
> — замість знака «крапка й тире» («. —»), який розділяє зони
>   бібліографічного опису, в бібліографічному посиланні рекомендовано
>   застосовувати знак «крапка» (при цьому в межах одного документа
>   застосування в бібліографічних посиланнях розділових знаків
>   уніфіковують);
>
> — відомості, запозичені не з титульної сторінки документа, дозволено
>   не брати у квадратні дужки;
>
> — після назви дозволено не зазначати загального позначення матеріалу
>   («Текст», «Електронний ресурс», «Карти», «Ноти» тощо — перелік згідно
>   з ДСТУ ГОСТ 7.1);
>
> — у складі вихідних даних дозволено не подавати найменування (ім'я)
>   видавця;
>
> **— у складі відомостей про фізичну характеристику документа можна зазначати або його загальний обсяг (наприклад: 285 с.), або номер
>   сторінки, на якій подано об'єкт посилання (наприклад: С. 19);**
>
> — дозволено не наводити відомостей про серію та Міжнародний
>   стандартний номер (ISBN, ISMN, ISSN).

А за посиланнями на цій сторінці можете знайти [підбірку прикладів оформлення бібліографічних посилань](http://library.nlu.edu.ua/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=1806:derzhavni-standarti-ukraini-dstu-do-oformlennya-disertaczijnix-robit).

**UPD.** Ще є стандарт [ДСТУ 3582:2013 Інформація та документація. Бібліографічний опис. Скорочення слів і словосполучень в українській мові.. Загальні вимоги та правила. (ISO 4:1984, NEQ; ISO 832:1994, NEQ). На заміну ДСТУ 3582-97.](http://web.archive.org/web/20180124071940/http://zakon.gbb.com.ua/regulations/10637/487553/) , яким визначено, що **`сторінка`** скорочується як **`с.`**

Comment: Тобто в сучасній українській мові (станом на 2017) наше Мін освіти визначає що скорочення **с.** - це стандарт, а скорочення  або **стор.** (яке я сам вважаю доречним)  - це взагалі не можна вживати?

Comment: @piznajko, напевно, можна вживати, але це буде не за стандартом.

Comment: @piznajko,  і Міносвіти не визначає, а посилається на чинний держстандарт.

Answer (score -5):

Дивна позиція:
*"с.", "стр." — ... Такі самі скорочення використовують в російській мові, і тому використання цих скорочень у сучасному українському мовознавстві є небажаним.*
А якщо в Росії кажуть "Полтава", то може, нам писати Пол**ь**тава - щоб не так, як у росіян? :)))

Щодо сторінок: сс. - такого в Україні в грамотній літературі **ніколи** не практикувалося. Хіба що СС-Галичина :))
стр. - теж **ніколи** не було. Хіба що в невичитаному самвидаві.

А є такі форми:
**с.** - позначення кількості сторінок (книги, журналу тощо). Наприклад: 176 с. (видання, що має 176 сторінок).
**С.** - позначення або **певної сторінки** (напр. С. 120 - щось на 120-й сторінці), або **діапазону сторінок** (С. 110-120 - щось розміщене від і до зазначених сторінок).

Це дуже лаконічна, зручна і зрозуміла форма.
А всі ці ЕсЕси, стр-нки, або аналогічні р. рр. чи Рр. та інші "ПоПи" в англомовних нормах - то їхня особиста справа, що росіян, що всього світу.

І приймати чиїсь норми, бо це агліцькі, чи навпаки відмовлятися, бо це російські... Пора жити своїми нормами.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE!
Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того,
що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Ми заохочуємо відповіді, які ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Необґрунтовані відповіді, що базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. Власна думка автора може бути *частиною* відповіді, але не її *основою*. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: Щодо того, що позиція «використовують в російській мові… тому використання… є небажаним» є дивною, абсолютно згоден (я сам це висловив у [своєму коментарі](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2603#comment4380_2603)). Однак щодо іншої частини відповіді — погодьтеся, що «ніколи такого не було, а завжди було так» — не дуже аргументоване твердження. Хтось інший може написати протилежну позицію в такому ж стилі — і як читач зрозуміє, хто з Вас правий (чи, може обидва праві, але надаєте перевагу різним матеріалам)? Наведіть приклади: **де** є такі форми (і чому Ви вважаєте, що іншого ніколи не було).